# Android NavigationItemSelectedListener did't work

Tags: android, navigationview

I learnded to use Android NavigationView,it was shown well but could't response to click event.

Here are my codes. I want to show a Toast when i click any item.but it doesn't work...

```
        nav = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    //nav.setClickable(true);
    nav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new      NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "caonima", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

<item android:icon="@drawable/homepage"
      android:title="首页"
    />
 <item android:id="@+id/psychology_item" android:title="日常心理学" android:icon="@drawable/right"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/recommand" android:title="用户推荐日报" android:icon="@drawable/right"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/movies" android:title="电影日报" android:icon="@drawable/right"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/internet" android:title="互联网安全" android:icon="@drawable/right"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/noboring" android:title="不许无聊" android:icon="@drawable/right"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/desingn" android:title="设计日报" android:icon="@drawable/right"/>

</group>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/tool_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

it has disturbed me for two days, i find some question use listView ,
or add drawerView.bringToFront();drawerView.requestLayout();
But nothing changed.

by the way , i used toolbar in a fragment like this

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_title,container,false);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar)v.findViewById(R.id.main_title_toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mToolbar.setTitle("首页");
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text));
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.navigation);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),mDrawerLayout,mToolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_shut){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            drawerView.bringToFront();
            drawerView.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    //mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i just so a article.it has solved my problem.
here is the link : [enter link description here](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/android-custom-navigation-drawer-not.html)

You just have to bring your drawerLayout to the front,
so try to use these two method

```
mDrawerLayout.bringToFront();
mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
```

then you can find it solved,if you want know more about this,search"Z order".